# How can I add a folder toolbar to Windows 10 taskbar with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, taskbar, jumplist

On the taskbar, you've always been able to right click on "Toolbars" and then "New Toolbar..." which will ask you for a folder to select. This folder would then appear as a separate toolbar on your taskbar which was a nice way to create a jump list of files (and also put a name on your taskbar).

Where is this stored? I've looked in the `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` and neighboring folders, but I don't see what I'm looking for there. As well, I've checked the registry for the name of a test folder that I created manually and I'm unable to find any reference.

I'd like to programmatically create this jump list folder as part of a PowerShell script, but I've been unable to figure out where it is stored on the computer nor has my Google-fu turned up any results.

Does anyone know where this would be stored so that I could create one with a script?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that information is stored in the registry under:
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop`
in the binary value named **TaskbarWinXP**.

No Toolbars:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   1/29/2020 - 2:23 PM
Value 0
  Name:            TaskbarWinXP
  Type:            REG_BINARY
  Data:            
00000000   0c 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 - 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010   aa 4f 28 68 48 6a d0 11 - 8c 78 00 c0 4f d9 18 b4  ªO(hHjÐ..x.ÀOÙ.´
00000020   b9 01 00 00 40 0d 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00  ¹...@.......-...
00000030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........l.......
00000040   01 00 00 00                                        ....
```

Added folder toolobar - **c:\quertykam**:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   2/8/2020 - 10:36 PM
Value 0
  Name:            TaskbarWinXP
  Type:            REG_BINARY
  Data:            
00000000   0c 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 - 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010   aa 4f 28 68 48 6a d0 11 - 8c 78 00 c0 4f d9 18 b4  ªO(hHjÐ..x.ÀOÙ.´
00000020   b9 01 00 00 c0 0c 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00  ¹...À.......-...
00000030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........l.......
00000040   01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 - b0 e2 2b d8 64 57 d0 11  ........°â+ØdWÐ.
00000050   a9 6e 00 c0 4f d7 05 a2 - 22 00 1c 00 08 10 00 00  ©n.ÀO×.¢".......
00000060   01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000070   00 00 00 00 4c 00 00 00 - 01 14 02 00 00 00 00 00  ....L...........
00000080   c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 - 81 01 00 00 10 00 00 00  À......F........
00000090   cb f5 39 24 02 df d5 01 - 42 18 ed 39 02 df d5 01  Ëõ9$.ßÕ.B.í9.ßÕ.
000000a0   42 18 ed 39 02 df d5 01 - 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  B.í9.ßÕ.........
000000b0   01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000c0   8b 00 14 00 1f 50 e0 4f - d0 20 ea 3a 69 10 a2 d8  .....PàOÐ ê:i.¢Ø
000000d0   08 00 2b 30 30 9d 19 00 - 2f 43 3a 5c 00 00 00 00  ..+00.../C:\....
000000e0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5c  ...............\
000000f0   00 31 00 00 00 00 00 49 - 50 51 24 10 00 51 57 45  .1.....IPQ$..QWE
00000100   52 54 59 7e 31 00 00 44 - 00 09 00 04 00 ef be 49  RTY~1..D. ...ï¾I
00000110   50 3d 24 49 50 51 24 2e - 00 00 00 07 0f 00 00 00  P=$IPQ$.........
00000120   00 1c 01 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000130   00 be 10 79 00 71 00 77 - 00 65 00 72 00 74 00 79  .¾.y.q.w.e.r.t.y
00000140   00 6b 00 61 00 6d 00 00 - 00 18 00 00 00 60 00 00  .k.a.m.......`..
00000150   00 03 00 00 a0 58 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 6a 70 00  .... X.......jp.
00000160   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 86 1a cf  ...............Ï
00000170   e3 45 f2 84 42 a9 d4 40 - 82 d3 01 1e b9 da 25 32  ãEò.B©Ô@.Ó..¹Ú%2
00000180   c9 c6 4a ea 11 9a 52 28 - c6 3f 1b 4a 85 86 1a cf  ÉÆJê..R(Æ?.J...Ï
00000190   e3 45 f2 84 42 a9 d4 40 - 82 d3 01 1e b9 da 25 32  ãEò.B©Ô@.Ó..¹Ú%2
000001a0   c9 c6 4a ea 11 9a 52 28 - c6 3f 1b 4a 85 45 00 00  ÉÆJê..R(Æ?.J.E..
000001b0   00 09 00 00 a0 39 00 00 - 00 31 53 50 53 b1 16 6d  . .. 9...1SPS±.m
000001c0   44 ad 8d 70 48 a7 48 40 - 2e a4 3d 78 8c 1d 00 00  D­.pH§H@.¤=x....
000001d0   00 68 00 00 00 00 48 00 - 00 00 0a 5e 35 7d 94 28  .h....H....^5}.(
000001e0   c4 4d ac ad 78 28 84 2a - 31 56 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÄM¬­x(.*1V......
000001f0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 c0 02 00 00 00 00  ..........À.....
00000200   00 00 52 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 00  ..R...........l.
00000210   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00                    ..........
```

I doubt you want to try to decode that structure, but it can be exported/imported to save/restore a **Toolbar**.